# React and Firebase - cant set the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set the state inside of a firebase snapshot function but I am getting an `Cannot read property 'setState' of null` error. I am not sure how to make it work.

This is my code:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid);

    dataGoalRef.child("mainGoal").on("value", function(mainGoalKeySnapshot) {
      var favoriteMainGoal = mainGoalKeySnapshot.val();
      console.log(favoriteMainGoal);

      var queryRef = dataGoalRef.orderByKey().equalTo(favoriteMainGoal);
      queryRef.on("value", snap => {
        this.setState({
          dataGoal: snap.val(),
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out. I wasn't binding the first method. So the solution is:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid);

    dataGoalRef.child("mainGoal").on("value", (mainGoalKeySnapshot) => {
      var favoriteMainGoal = mainGoalKeySnapshot.val();
      console.log(favoriteMainGoal);

      var queryRef = dataGoalRef.orderByKey().equalTo(favoriteMainGoal);
      queryRef.on("value", snap => {
        this.setState({
          dataGoal: snap.val(),
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using arrow function instead of normal function declaration for callback which you have passed in `dataGoalRef.child("mainGoal").on("value", function(mainGoalKeySnapshot){})`

updated code

```
dataGoalRef.child("mainGoal").on("value", (mainGoalKeySnapshot) => {
 ....
 ....
});
```